# CSS: pseudo selector for transformed elements

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-transforms, pseudo-class

Is there a (future) pseudo selector to get elements which have been transformed by the css transform property? i think of something like this:

```
div:transformed{
 color:red;
}
```

Comment: Simply..No. There isn't and, *as far as i know*, none is expected or proposed.

Comment: If you tell us what you need this for, perhaps we could help you find an alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such pseudo selector. The following javascript code might serve your purpose:

```js
var element = document.querySelectorAll('div');
for (i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
  var value = window.getComputedStyle(element[i]).getPropertyValue("transform");
  if (value != "") //Or suitable comparator
  {
    element[i].style.color = "red";
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  transform: translateX(10px);
}
```

```html
<div>Text</div>
```

Comment: although I had hoped for a pure css solution, this interim javascript approach solved my problem so far. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such selector.